# Animated loading around UIButton with BezierPath

Tags: swift

My goal is to make loading around UIButton that looks like that:

[image]

Here we don't have start point and end point of the bezier. The lines should look exactly as in the image and the animation must be infinity. So we have a line that is lets say half of the button width size, dots and then empty space. They should be static sizes and the rotation should be constant.

So far I tried with 2 BezierPaths once start from the beginning of the button the other one from the middle and with different animations strokeStart and strokeEnd but the results is not so close to the actual result

[image]

The code is just 2 CAShapeLayers and 2 CABasicAnimations. Any help will be much appreciated

[image]

I don't have entire animation of expected results, because I only got the image, but the idea is the dashed lines as well as the stroke to follow the white line infinity.

Comment: Can you add an animation of the expected result, please?

Comment: I don't have the actual animation because I received only the image, I edited the question at the bottom you can see the image. Dashed line and the stroke color should follow the white line infinity. Its like spinning around the button. On my image imagine the empty space is actually the white line. And I should always have this empty space unlike my example where at some point the two lines are getting into 1 point combining